# Rank based accumulation in stata

Tags: stata

I am working on a  test score database and want to build two observations. The data has rows English score, Math score, Rank and a unique id for each kid. Let's call the kid for whom we are building the observations "focal kid"

1. **Obs 1** average English score of all kids ranked below focal kid whose Math score is above that of the focal kid
2. **Obs 2** average English score of all kids ranked below focal kid whose Math score is below that of the focal kid's

Please help me write this code without loops if possible. ( I have about 100k observations)

**Update 1** I am building these observations for each kid and not just one kid.

Comment: Do you plan on computing these two values just once, for one particular kid that you have identified, or computing them for each of the 100k kids? Makes a big difference if you're doing it just once, or if you mean to add two extra values to each of your 100k observations.

Comment: I wish it was for just one kid. That would be simpler for me. This is for each kid.  That's what is scaring me.

Comment: In that case, more information about your data may be helpful. What values do the ranks take on - 1 to 100,000, or are the ranks something like percentiles - 1 to 100? What values do the math scores take on? I think looping will be unavoidable, but perhaps if there are few enough combinations of rank and math scores, you could avoid calculating the same combinations repeatedly.

Comment: Ranks are from 1 to ~100k. Overlaps are there but are fewer in number.

Comment: Also, all scores are percentage scores up to 3 decimal points

Comment: I'm bowing out. I see no alternative to looping, since for each kid you must somehow compare both their rank and their math score to the rank and math score of every other kid. When it's just one variable being compared, like rank, sorting will allow you to make all the comparisons at once, as it were. But with two variables, I don't see anything that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Loops!

```
* toy dataset  
clear
set obs 5 
set seed 2803 
gen id = _n 
gen rnd = runiform()
sort rnd 
gen rank = _n 
gen math = 100 * runiform() 
gen english = 100 * runiform() 

* code for real   
gen math_above = . 
gen math_below = .

sort rank  

forval j = 2/`=_N' { 
    local J = `j' - 1 
    su english if math > math[`j'] in 1/`J', meanonly 
    replace math_above = r(mean) in `j' 

    su english if math < math[`j'] in 1/`J', meanonly 
    replace math_below = r(mean) in `j' 
}
```